# 1 variable with 2 different values QlikView LoadScript

Tags: database, statistics, data-visualization, qlikview, qliksense

I need to put 2 different values for 1 variable in the LoadScript of a report.

I am using the syntax with let -

```
LET Customer_name  ='XXXX';

LET Customer_name  ='YYYY';
```

But when I load data, I have data only for one customer but not the second one as well.

Comment: Could you please share (or explain) how this variable is utilized?

Comment: Hi, I solved the issue adding two different variables... Let Customer_name1 and Let Customer_name2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem -

I created 2 variables -

```
LET Customer_name  ='XXXX';

LET Customer_name2  ='YYYY';
```

and in the Load Script I called them in the WHERE CLAUSE with OR.

```
WHERE Customer_name = 'XXXX' OR Customer_name2 = 'YYYY';
```